# How to achieve continuous service with mesos-dns on application upgrade in marathon?

Tags: dns, mesos, marathon, redeploy

I have a simple web app running in marathon. In order to give users access to it, I use mesos-dns. By design, it only updates its dns tables each 60 seconds. So whenever I upgrade the application there might be up to 60 seconds window during which users will be using stale dns entry that results in 503 (Service Unavailable).

How to fix or workaround this issue?

Comment: Are you using DC/OS?

Comment: Have you seen https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/blue-green-deploy.html To be honest, I don't really understood where the 503 seems to occur... Are you meaning marathon-lb instead of Mesos DNS?

Comment: @MichaelHausenblas No

Comment: @Tobi sounds like the approach I need. Is there a ready-to-use library that provides that? In my case it's enough to just keep the blue version running for a period of 60 seconds. With the current tools (jenkins marathon plugin), the default upgrade procedure only insures that the green version is running and kills the blue version immediately.